# On demand new IPv6 using privacy extension?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, ip, ipv6, privacy

Enabling `Privacy Extension` (`net.ipv6.conf.eth0.use_tempaddr=2`  in `/etc/sysctl.conf`) for `IPv6` gives me a new IP address for a fixed period of time, is there a way to get a new IPv6 on demand? i.e. refresh a new IPv6 when needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "active" temporary address has properties *temporary* and *dynamic* but not *deprecated*. When it's about to become deprecated (ie: its *preferred_lft* value drops to 0), a new temporary address is added by the kernel to the interface.

The interface's current temporary address, will be part of the results shown here:

```
ip -6 address show temporary dynamic
```

but not part of the older addresses which are still valid but deprecated shown with:

```
ip -6 address show temporary deprecated
```

You just have to lower its `preferred_lft` property to near zero to trigger the creation of the new temporary address. From trial and error, this won't work if `preferred_lft` is set below 3: the countdown reaches 0 before triggering the creation and then it won't work anymore (but one can still set again `preferred_lft` to >= 3 later to get the trigger). I don't know if there's any knob about this peculiarity. 5 seconds looks like a safe value, meaning the new address will appear about 2 or 3 seconds later.

Let's suppose the current found value is 2001:db8::1/64 on interface *eth0*:

```
ip address change 2001:db8::1/64 dev eth0 preferred_lft 5
```

Note that tampering with this removes the *dynamic* property, which would have not happened naturally, and might possibly trigger later creation of additional temporary addresses sooner than expected.

---

With `ip`'s JSON output and [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) some scriptability is possible, here's what I came with to output the commands ready to pipe to a shell to change all candidate temporary addresses at once (usually requires a multi-homed system to get more than one but tampering with this might perhaps create multiple ones later too). It verifies that the *temporary* and *dynamic* address is not *deprecated* to consider it a candidate:

```
ip -6 -p -j address show temporary dynamic | jq -j '.[] |
    . as $i |
        .addr_info[] as $a |
            if $a.local == null // $a.deprecated == true then
                empty
            else
                "ip -6 address change ",
                $a.local, "/", $a.prefixlen,
                " dev ", $i.ifname,
                " preferred_lft 5\n"
            end'
```

which would output again:

```
ip -6 address change 2001:db8::1/64 dev eth0 preferred_lft 5
```

You might consider also reducing `valid_lft` to have the now deprecated address disappear completely faster.

Comment: Your solution had provided me quite a lot of insight into how things work with IPv6, my usage scenario is something like this -> my python script initiates an external download using IPv6, I want a new IPv6 on every invocation of the script, I guess this won't be possible with above (5 second). I would further like to clarify A). If I disable privacy extension can I randomly assign IPv6 IP's from my subnet as source IP's? If yes a python example would be helpful? B). Using privacy extensions what happens to my ongoing/established downloads when the temp address becomes depreceated?

Comment: A/ you'll have to check if duplicate address detection is still honoured: keep `ip -6 monitor address` running and check if there is any temporary "tentative" status appearing and disappearing: that means DAD was done and didn't fail. DAD appears to require about 1/2s. A2/ you can add an address in addition to the privacy mechanism, without having to disable it  B/ as long as valid_lft doesn't reach 0, the address is still usable (but not selected unless explicitly bound). That means anything currently using it is unaffected.